# Armature Invisible?

Tags: rigging, 3d-view, armature

So, in my project, I have a rigged model that I'm attempting to animate. However whenever I make a new 3d viewport (like when switching from default to animation mode), that viewport won't show the armature of the model. I ended up joining a new viewport with the only one that *did* show the armature, and now it won't show on that viewport and I don't know what to do. I haven't hidden the armature or anything, so I imagine the issue has to do with a 3D viewport setting I'm not experienced enough to know about. Any advice?

[image: BTW, the problem isn't that it's obscured by the shark either, because the head bone pokes out of the shark's nose regardless and it doesn't appear when I hide the shark either.]

Also, it's worth noting that when I create new bones, they are visible. Only the existing bones can't be seen.

Comment: Go into pose mode. In the outliner you should see a little eye next to each bone, if this is off the bone will be hidden. Shift click the `+` in front of the armature to expand all bones.

Comment: Not the issue, unfortunately. I checked this several times before posting the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just for those who might find this in the future - I had the same problem and fixed it by simply closing and re-opening the file.

Comment: In my case, it required re-enabling the collection containing the armature.

Answer (score 1):

A solution: I had the same issue and realized I clicked off the initial Layer box in the Armature tab in the Pose menu
2.9.2

Comment: Hello and welcome, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer, low quality posts may be removed at some point. Could you edit your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works? Perhaps add a few screenshots illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) otherwise it may be converted into a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If this doesn't work for anyone, something I found out is that the armature is hidden in sculpt mode. If you are in sculpt mode switch to layout. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the rebar was gone but I didn't remove them. I solved this problem by simply selecting view/local view/Toggle local view and it helped[image]